# How To Reference Node Modules from TypeScript in ASP.Net Core Web Project

Tags: node.js, typescript, asp.net-core

I've installed npm library [xrm-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xrm-mock) into an ASP.Net Core Web Application.  It is showing up in the npm folder and the node_module folder on the disk:
[image]

I have a file located at `test\formTemplate\contact.ts` that attempts to import it with this on the first line:

```ts
import { XrmMockGenerator, XrmMock } from "xrm-mock";
```

But VS shows underlines "xrm-mock" as an exception `(TS) Cannot find module 'xrm-mock'`

Here is my tsconfig.json located at the root of my web project:

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "umd",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "es6-promise",
      "jasmine",
      "steal",
      "xrm"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./webresources/new_/common/*.ts",
    "./webresources/new_/scripts/*.ts",
    "./webresources/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

[image]

Do I need to somehow specific the `node_modules` folder somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a couple root causes of this issue.  First was that I was importing XrmMock incorrectly.  The index for XrmMock is as follows:

```
export * from "./xrm-mock/index";
export { XrmMockGenerator } from "./xrm-mock-generator/index";
```

which means that my import should have looked like this:

```
import * as XrmMock from "xrm-mock";
import { XrmMockGenerator } from "xrm-mock";
```

The other issue was with Visual Studio itself.  I ran `tsc` in the root the web project and fixed all compile errors, and then I restarted Visual Studio.  After that, everything started working correctly.  (I also had to disable ReSharper, but that is fairly common since ReSharper has a very hard time keeping up with the rapid pace of TS)